# Упаковка Python проекта в единый exe файл

Tags: python, exe, проект

У меня есть готовый проект на python с графическим интерфейсом. В проекте присутствуют звуки и картинки. Мне нужно собрать ВЕСЬ проект в exe файл. Есть ли способ сделать это? То есть, я знаю способ, как собрать в exe файл только 1 скрипт, но мне, для удобства, нужно чтобы пользователь скачивал только 1 exe файл и у него все работало - картинки, звуки... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать, спасибо.

Comment: например, pyinstaller

Comment: Да, я так и делал, но pyinstaller требует, чтобы в папке с exe-файлом лежали все картинки и звуки, иначе программа просто не работает. Это не проблема положить рядом картинки и звуки, однако для пользователей, скачивающих программу, будет весьма трудоемко скачивать сразу несколько файлов и класть их в одно место.

Comment: уверен, можно настроить так чтобы тот положил ресурсы в exe. Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264169/ еще пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966932/5909792

Comment: Большое спасибо! А звуки, типа mp3 таким же образом добавлять?

Comment: Да, как и любые файлы, которые хотите в exe вложить. Кст, как закончите с этим, поделитесь, пожалуйста, результатом в ответ )

Comment: Вот: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gHYECxhX9TbkA0rv1OBbTamZXA7qFrHD. Проект пока что очень сухой и работает только на windows, но главное, что работает. Пока что могу представить его только на google диске.

Comment: Ну, я имел ввиду чтобы в ответе показали как pyinstaller настроили и как обращались к вложенным ресурсам :) А так, лучше не на файлообменнике храните а например на github (gitlab, bitbucket, <еще аналоги>)