# Как скомпилировать в единый бинарный файл приложение на Python в Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Нашел только этот вопрос [Упаковка Python проекта в единый exe файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924792/182065) он про Windows.

В питоне есть такие вещи как типо

`make`

или

`cargo build`

после которых получаешь независимый от библиотек и прочего бинарный файл?

Comment: В чистом виде не бывает, всё что есть — костыли, просто запаковывающие интерпретатор и библиотеки в один архив, и это не является компиляцией (в Windows то же самое)

Comment: Pyinstaller, да вообще-то почти любая инструция от винды также сработает

Comment: а как же очень известный проект типо youtube-dl у которого в релизах находится бинарный файл без всяких зависимостей? или они тоже костыли городят с закапыванием интерпретатора? 

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/latest/download/youtube-dl

Comment: А в код посмотреть слабо? https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: @Ivan да, у youtube-dl тоже костыли. Если вы скормите этот бинарный файл в unzip, то он найдёт в этом файле архив и распакует оттуда библиотеки. А вот интерпретртора в этом файле нет — он должен быть установлен в систему заранее. Если же вы скачаете виндовый youtube-dl.exe, то там в комплекте будет ещё интерпретатор Python 3.4.4 (в виде dll-файла перед архивом) и в архиве стандартные библиотеки для него. Это всё тоже не компиляция, просто упаковка в самораспаковывающийся архив.

Comment: понял. спасибо.